# why cant I do this in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
  if !row[0].include? 'Changed database' || !row[0].starts_with? '---' || !row[0].include? "rows affected" || !row[0].nil? || !row[0] == ""
```

if i do

```
if !row[0].include? 'Changed database'
```

it works well but if i do multiple conditions then it fails on this error

```
SyntaxError: /Users/tamer/Sites/active/app/models/account.rb:42: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting kTHEN or ':' or '\n' or ';'
 ...ase' || !row[0].starts_with? '---' || !row[0].include? "rows...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes the parser can't guess at how you're grouping arguments.

In your example, it's interpreting `'Changed database' || !row[0].starts_with?` as the argument passed to `include?`, and is choking when it comes across the next token, `'---'`, which then makes no sense.

Adding parentheses to clear up the ambiguity will solve the problem, e.g.:

```
if !row[0].include?('Changed database') || !row[0].starts_with?('---') || !row[0].include?("rows affected") || !row[0].nil? || !row[0] == ""
```

If you really, really hate parentheses, you could also switch to using `or` instead of `||`, which has a weaker precedence and will be applied later, e.g.:

```
if !row[0].include? 'Changed database' or !row[0].starts_with? '---' or !row[0].include? "rows affected" or !row[0].nil? or !row[0] == ""
```

Comment: Or use `or` instead of `||`, it has lower precedence.

Comment: And that's why "optional" parentheses in Ruby are not so optional. One must admit it looks nice to write parentheses-less DSLs, but otherwise it wasn't such a great idea.